# Javascript Prompt displaying executed value

Tags: javascript

I've this code:

```
<input type="button" value="Test Short URL" onClick="javascript:void(location.href='http://taimoorsultan.com/y/yourls-api.php?signature=05e2685fc7&format=simple&action=shorturl&url='+escape(location.href))&prompt('Shorten URL', 'shorturl');">
```

Actually this code takes url and process it and show a shorten url on next blank page. I was trying to display that shorten url on the same page through prompt().
Using the above code is bit confusing for me. 
How I can process the short url without allowing it to display the result on next page?

I think I should first process the action="" and then do something to show results within a prompt box. But don't know how to do this.
Help please!

Comment: Well, assigning a value to `location.href` will redirect the browser to that location. If you don't want that, don't do it. As for the rest of your question, it's not completely clear what you are trying to achieve. Please [**edit your question**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14292978/edit) and provide more information. A http://jsfiddle.net/ demo would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

> I think I should first process the action="" and then do something to show results within a prompt box.

Use the following process:

- Have `action` be the aforementioned .php URL
- Have `button` be `submit`
- Remove `onclick`
- Add an iframe with an ID of `foo`
- Have `target` be `"#foo"`