# How to Avoid redirection in this Javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript Prompt displaying executed value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292978/javascript-prompt-displaying-executed-value)

I know i can insert prompt() in this code, but want to know how to stop this script to show result on another page. I'm trying to show the result on the same page through prompt.

```
<input type="button" value="Short URL" onClick="javascript:void(location.href='http://taimoorsultan.com/y/yourls-api.php?signature=05e2685fc7&format=simple&action=shorturl&url='+escape(location.href));">
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use AJAX  if you want to show result on the same page

Comment: I'm sorry, but i was not getting any reply there!

Comment: @Saju Thanks for your suggestion, can you please provide an example or more information? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please check this previous question on SO [What is the best ajax tutorial site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602628/what-is-the-best-ajax-tutorial-site).

If you are using a library like Jquery (which is highly recommended), it will have the wrappers to make your coding simple.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

By Using JQuery AJAX, you can show result on same page

Browser [here](http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/107)

Download source files [Here](http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/sites/default/files/ajax01.tar.gz)